# Why do I get this error when trying to use Multer for dynamic path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

```
app.post('/upload/image', multer({
  dest:  './public/users/',
  changeDest: function(dest, req, res) {
      var newDestination = dest ;
      var stat = null;
      try {
          stat = fs.statSync(newDestination);
      } catch (err) {
          fs.mkdirSync(newDestination);
      }
      if (stat && !stat.isDirectory()) {
          throw new Error("directory cant be created");
      }
      return newDestination
  }
  }), function(req, res) {
       res.send({"status":"success"})
  });
```

I tried using this code so that I can dynamically set the path for multer to store the uploaded pictures from the client. But this code is giving me this error

```
    throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]
    at Route.<computed> [as post] (/Volumes/MacExtnd/Programming/webshop/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202:15)
    at Function.app.<computed> [as post] (/Volumes/MacExtnd/Programming/webshop/backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:482:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/MacExtnd/Programming/webshop/backend/server.js:733:5)
```

Please can anyone tell me how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

`multer(opts)` return an object with properties like `.single()`, `.none()`. [See docs here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#multeropts).

You are passing this object as an Express middleware function, which explains the error. You would want to chose the correct property and pass that instead.

Example from the docs:

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Comment: But I want to pass in the path as a url param in app.post()